# add nodes to jtree from another jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtree

How can i add dynamically(from `textField` )nodes to `jtree` in another `jframe`?
here is my little code :

```
final First_JFRame frame= new First_JFRame();
DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) frame.tree.getModel();
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
          DefaultMutableTreeNode firstNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("firstNode") ;
          root.add(firstNode);
    firstNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("firstleaf"));
    firstNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("secondleaf"));
    model.reload(root);
```

knowing that `jtree` declared as public static

Comment: What part of that question are you actually have problems with? Adding nodes to a `JTree`? Passing information from one class to another? Knowing when the user has something to add?

Comment: i actually tried to add the value in my text field in frame2 as a node to jtree in frame1 but it did not work,but in the same jframe it worked

Comment: *"..from another jframe"* 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"knowing that `jtree` declared as public static"* It probably should be neither (public nor static).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example on how to get desired action.
Basically you just need to pass the instance of you Jtree to second frame and than add Nodes to it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
                frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


                JTree tree = new JTree();
                DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
                DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
                DefaultMutableTreeNode firstNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("firstNode") ;
                root.add(firstNode);
                firstNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("firstleaf"));
                firstNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("secondleaf"));
                model.reload();
                frame1.add(tree);
                frame1.pack();
                frame1.setVisible(true);

                JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
                frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(frame1);
                JTextField text = new JTextField(15);
                JButton add = new JButton("ADD");
                frame2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                frame2.add(text);
                frame2.add(add);
                frame2.pack();
                frame2.setVisible(true);

                add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        firstNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(text.getText()));
                        model.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Or, use an observer pattern so you can decouple the code